# What is a more efficient way for me to calculate the sum of an array, without using sum()?

Tags: python, arrays, sum

So, my code looks like this. Essentially, what I want to do is minimise functions calculateSumX, calculateSumY and calculateSumZ into one function. How would I do that? Ignore case for now.

```
def calculateSumX(x):
    theSumX = 0

    for i in x:
        theSumX = theSumX + 1
        return theSumX;

def CalculateSumY(y):
    theSumY = 0

    for i in y:
        theSumY = theSumY + 1
        return theSumY;

def calculateSumZ(z):
    theSumZ = 0

    for i in z:
        theSumZ = theSumZ + 1
        return theSumZ;

def question5(x, y, z):

    case = 5

    #tests whether the sum of each array is equal 

    x = calculateSumX(x)
    y = calculateSumY(y)
    z = calculateSumZ(z)

    if x == y == z:
        print("The sum of all three arrays have equal values ")
        case = 1
        return case

    # if x and y equal
    elif x == y:
        print("The sum of x and y hold equal values ")
        case = 2
        return case

    # if x and z equal 
    elif x == z:
        print("The sum of x and z hold equal values ")
        case = 3
        return case

    # if y and z equal 
    elif y == z:
        print("The sum of y and z hold equal values ")
        case = 4
        return case

    # if all three different
    else:
        print("No sum of each array hold equal values ")
        return case
```

Comment: Please give example inputs to your functions. It's not clear what you mean by `array`. Do you mean NumPy array? XArray? List? Something else?

Comment: The function are all the same anyway. Take any one of them, rename it to just `calculateSum`, and call it 3 times with the different arguments. I feel you fundamentally misunderstand what a function is - there are plenty of tutorials available online (SO is not the place for one).

Answer (score 2):

This;

```
def calculateSumX(x):
    theSumX = 0

    for i in x:
        theSumX = theSumX + 1
        return theSumX;

def CalculateSumY(y):
    theSumY = 0

    for i in y:
        theSumY = theSumY + 1
        return theSumY;

def calculateSumZ(z):
    theSumZ = 0

    for i in z:
        theSumZ = theSumZ + 1
        return theSumZ;


x = calculateSumX(x)
y = calculateSumY(y)
z = calculateSumZ(z)
```

can simply be turned in to this;

```
def calculate_sum(ls):
    total = 0
    for value in ls:
        total += value
    return total


sum_x = calculate_sum(x)
sum_y = calculate_sum(y)
sum_z = calculate_sum(z)
```

Btw, your original calculateSum functions will not calculate the sum, but will return the amount of elements in the list, and actually will not even do that, because they return after the first element.